# How to convert iris.csv into sci kit format with data and target?

Tags: python, csv, scikit-learn

I've downloaded the classic iris.csv file (https://gist.github.com/netj/8836201) and trying to work a k-nearest without using the sci kit datasets.load_iris() feature.

I would like to replace the `datasets.load_iris()` with my own CSV, in order to modify it and use it later with my own data.
For this code I get this error:

`ValueError: n_samples=1 should be >= n_clusters=8`

Code:

```
print(__doc__)

%matplotlib notebook
from pandas import read_csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import datasets

np.random.seed(5)

iris = read_csv('iris.csv')
iris = iris.values
X = iris[:,3] # features
y = iris[:,4] # target

estimators = [('k_means_iris_8', KMeans(n_clusters=8)),
          ('k_means_iris_3', KMeans(n_clusters=3)),
          ('k_means_iris_bad_init', KMeans(n_clusters=3, n_init=1,
                                           init='random'))]

fignum = 1
titles = ['8 clusters', '3 clusters', '3 clusters, bad initialization']
for name, est in estimators:
    fig = plt.figure(fignum, figsize=(4, 3))
    ax = Axes3D(fig, rect=[0, 0, .95, 1], elev=48, azim=134)
    est.fit(X)
    labels = est.labels_

    ax.scatter(X[:, 3], X[:, 0], X[:, 2],
               c=labels.astype(np.float), edgecolor='k')

    ax.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    ax.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    ax.w_zaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    ax.set_xlabel('Petal width')
    ax.set_ylabel('Sepal length')
    ax.set_zlabel('Petal length')
    ax.set_title(titles[fignum - 1])
    ax.dist = 12
    fignum = fignum + 1

fig = plt.figure(fignum, figsize=(4, 3))
ax = Axes3D(fig, rect=[0, 0, .95, 1], elev=48, azim=134)

for name, label in [('Setosa', 0),
                    ('Versicolour', 1),
                    ('Virginica', 2)]:
    ax.text3D(X[y == label, 3].mean(),
              X[y == label, 0].mean(),
              X[y == label, 2].mean() + 2, name,
              horizontalalignment='center',
              bbox=dict(alpha=.2, edgecolor='w', facecolor='w'))

y = np.choose(y, [1, 2, 0]).astype(np.float)
ax.scatter(X[:, 3], X[:, 0], X[:, 2], c=y, edgecolor='k')

ax.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.w_zaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.set_xlabel('Petal width')
ax.set_ylabel('Sepal length')
ax.set_zlabel('Petal length')
ax.set_title('Ground Truth')
ax.dist = 12
fig.show(
```

Answer (score 2):

you should also encode the labels, else it won't work. I've dowload it too, and changing just the code as below allow me to run perfectly. (apart from the missing closing ')' at the end of the code but i think is copy paste mistake)

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

np.random.seed(5)

iris = read_csv('iris.csv')
iris = iris.values
X = iris[:,:4] # features
y = le.fit_transform(iris[:,4]) # target
```

Comment: I just noticed that and was about the edit my answer, but you found it. +1

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
X = iris[:,3]
```

Then X is only a single column (4th feature `petal.width`), which is why you are getting error in `est.fit()` part, because the estimator think you have only a single sample (I'm assuming you are using an older version of scikit-learn. Newer versions throw a different more clear error there)

Correct that to:

```
X = iris[:,:4]
```

to use all features.

Why are you doing `y = np.choose(y, [1, 2, 0]).astype(np.float)`?

Comment: I'm using the np.choose to reorder the labels and to have colors matching the cluster results. By changing the X to 4, it works but I get one more error --> could not convert string to float: 'Virginica'. Is there a way to make to adjust it? I'm a self learner and i'm trying to make it work. Thank you again

Comment: @PierFilippoPaoletti On which line are you getting the error?  Have you done what was said in other answer here?

Comment: @PierFilippoPaoletti You re-order the labels, but then dont reorder the X, do then final data wont match. I dont think this is what you want.

Comment: you've noticed what he hasn't. @PierFilippoPaoletti you need to encode the lables. It won't work if you don't. Please read the other answer.